# Create a Geotiff with different colors

Tags: raster, java, geotiff-tiff, geotools, color

I have a geotiff raster image.
I have estracted the WritableRaster, the envelope, and the gridsampleDimension I need to create a new geotiff using Geotools.

```
GridCoverageFactory gcf = new GridCoverageFactory();
GridCoverage2D image2 = gcf.create(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), raster2, envelope, gridSampleDimensions);
String url = "D:\\ImmaginiRaster\\2015\\" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "--.tif";
File file = new File(url);
GeoTiffWriter writer = new GeoTiffWriter(file);
writer.write(image2, null);
```

And this works perfectly well.
Also if I set a random valure for the pixel using

```
 raster2.setPixel(i, j, [RANDOM]);
```

But this image is in b/w.
I want to create a new image in RGB.

I've tried using and IndexColorModel

```
int nColors = 8;
Random rn = new Random();
byte b000 = (byte) 0;
byte b255 = (byte) 255;
byte[] reds = new byte[]{b255, b255, b000, b000, b255, b255, b000, b000};
byte[] greens = new byte[]{b255, b255, b255, b255, b000, b000, b000, b000};
byte[] blues = new byte[]{b255, b000, b255, b000, b255, b000, b255, b000};;

IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(3, nColors, reds, greens, blues);
raster2 = colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {//width...

        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                raster2.setSample(i, j, 0, rn.nextInt(200));
                raster2.setSample(i, j, 1, rn.nextInt(200));
                raster2.setSample(i, j, 2, rn.nextInt(200));
        }
}
```

I've also tried with

```
BufferedImage imagex = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
TiledImage tiledImage = new TiledImage(0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, imagex.getSampleModel(), imagex.getColorModel() );
raster2 = tiledImage.getWritableTile(0, 0);
```

But I receive always a message like this

> width = 1304 height = 567 #Bands = 3 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0 is incompatible with ColorModel ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 1 color space = ScaledColorSpace[32767.0, 32767.0] transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false

Where am i wrong ?

Comment: try TYPE_INT_RGBA to include transparency

Comment: Nothing, quite same error

_IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 1304 height = 567 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0 is incompatible with ColorModel ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 1 color space = ScaledColorSpace[32767.0, 32767.0] transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false_



I've added also  :

`raster2.setSample(i, j, 3, 100);`

BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB

Answer (score 1):

I can't get my head around `IndexColorModel` but for a use case like your second one I see the same error with your code but if I create the `WritableRaster` using this line all works as expected.

```
WritableRaster raster2 = 
    RasterFactory.createBandedRaster(java.awt.image.DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, w,
    h, 3, null);
```